# Text in \AddToShipoutPictureBG

Tags: backgrounds, parbox, eso-pic

I would like to put some text in the command `\AddToShipoutPictureBG`  the desired output is printed in red on the picture. How can I do this ?

I've tried using `Foot left \hfill \page \hfill Foot right` but it doesn't work. The second problem is that `Foot left` is not centered according to the rule.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,landscape,footinclude=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{eso-pic,rotating,xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \rule{\dimexpr
      0.8cm-2pt}{\paperheight}}
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\color{white}\sffamily\rotatebox{90}{Foot left}}
}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add the text in a box, for example a `\parbox{\paperheight}{text}` otherwise `\hfill` would not make sense.

Comment: Thanks. The `paradox`should be after the `rotatebox` ?

Comment: Inside you want to rotate the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

The following code works fine.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn,landscape,footinclude=false]{scrbook}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{eso-pic,rotating,xcolor}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \rule{\dimexpr
      0.8cm-2pt}{\paperheight}}
    \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace{0.1cm}
    \color{white}\sffamily\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{\paperheight}{\quad Foot left \hfill 1 \hfill Foot right h\quad\:}}}
}

\begin{document}

Test

\end{document}
```

[image]